# Matching in $n$ by $b$ bipartite graph

Tags: graph-theory, matching-theory

I found in a book the following corollary of Hall's theorem:

> Let $G=(A,B,E)$ be a bipartite graph. Suppose that $|A|=|B|=n$. If the minimal degree of $G$ is at least $n/2$ then $G$ has a matching.

I know how to prove that if the minimal degree of vertices in A is less than the maximal degree of vertices in B then $G$ has a matching, but apparently the strategy I used for this proof isn't working for the above corollary.

Any ideas?

Comment: FYI: raising the minimal degree only one step higher to $n/2+1$ provably implies even more: a *Hamilton circuit* (and *conjecturally* implies even more: a bipartite-square of a Hamilton circuit). Here, a 'bipartite-square of a Hamilton-circuit is the graph obtained from a circuit of length $2n$ by choosing an arbitrary vertex, and henceforth adding-in *all* edges connecting vertices which have distance $=3$ on the circuit. So, there is a very simple-to-state open problem in the immediate vicinity of this question. (Incidentally, I once proved the version with $n/2+\epsilon n$ instead $n/2+1$.)

Answer (score 2):

By Hall's condition, it suffices to show that $|\Gamma(S)|\geq |S|$ for all $S\subseteq A$ and $S\subseteq B$. Let $S\subseteq A$. If $S=\emptyset$, then $|\Gamma(S)|\geq 0=|S|$. Assume further that $S\neq\emptyset$. If $|S|\leq \frac n 2$, then $|\Gamma(S)|\geq|\Gamma(v)|\geq\frac n 2$ where $v\in S$. If $|S|>\frac n 2$, then $|\Gamma(S)|=|B|\geq |S|$. Hence, the result follows.

Comment: Why if $|S|>\frac n 2$, then $|\Gamma(S)|=|B|$?

Comment: @user236236 Because for $v\in B$ has at least $\frac n 2$ many neighbours in $A$ and one of them must be in $S$ as $|S|>\frac n 2$.